# face-api.js --- recognition live server issue

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to run this face detection app (JavaScript) without using live server I tried local host also didn't work just white blank page its only working when using live server this is the source code (https://github.com/codeSTACKr/Face-Detection)

Comment: You are getting blank page because Fetch API cannot load local .json files. You can track errors via Browser's Console. If you change Fetch API calls with Jquery.Get method, it will work properly

Comment: @Kaan you where right i found the errors in browser console but i didn't understand your answer the errors were (fetch API cannot load) (uncaught (in promise) type error : failed to fetch can you tell me the answer please in details like what to do please ?)